# Viewflipper is running oncreate method when flipping?

Tags: android, viewflipper

Im on mobile right now so I can't post code, but I dont think it is necessary for this problem. Basically I have a class that gets initialized when the 'main' view is shown then it gets filled with information gathered from the second view, then flips back to the 'main'  view to get filled with more info and repeat. However the class keeps getting initialized whenever I go back to the first view and there for running the default constructors of the class and erasing the information. I am using showNext() to switch views.

Answer (score 0):

ViewFlipper doesnt not alters the application lifecicle, since it is just a view, as you can see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html. There is for sure something else you are not doing correctly. Some code would help.

Also, please note that some runtime config changes, even an screen orientation, will actually restart your activity, and that could be the problem.  You can find more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)